# How do I right justify text in Lua?

Tags: text, sdk, lua, alignment, coronasdk

I've tried several examples on how to right justify text in Lua. So far, I have been unsuccessful. I am using Corona Sdk. Any advice is appreciated.
Jerry

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
local textObj = display.newText(.....);
textObj:setReferencePoint(display.CenterRightReferencePoint);
textObj.x = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

In new builds of Corona SDK that have graphics 2.0, you need to do this:

```
rowScore.anchorX = 1
```

Where `rowScore` is your variable created with `display.newText`.
Here's a full example:

```
local rowScore = display.newText({
    text="My Score", 
    fontSize=40 
})
rowScore.anchorX = 1
rowScore.x = 30
rowScore.y = 100
```

Notice that I didn't used the `align="right"` parameter because it was working on the Windows Simulator but it was not working on Android.